# Power Pivot Refresh Errors

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have a power pivot model that links its data to an external excel document.  Every month I have to update the excel document with new data coming in.

In the past when trying to update it would somehow "forget" it was connected to that data source.  But by re-establishing the connection I could refresh.

This month it again wouldn't refresh but re-establishing the connection didn't work.  I was wondering if the issue was with the excel document so I tried to re-upload the document as a new table and it worked fine, I even managed to refresh it.

I can't use that new one, though, because it would take way too long to re-establish all the connections and pivot tables

So, to be clear, when I refresh the table I get the following error message.
[image]

But when I try to test connection I get this error message.
[image]

What could be causing it not to refresh if the connection is there?

Edit:  When I click on error details it tells me to check the connection.
[image]

Comment: And when you click on Error details?

Comment: @JosWoolley It tells me to go check the connection.  Sorry I forgot to mention that, will add it in an edit.